# Unable to see Revision History in Azure Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, revision-history

Recently, I cannot find my revision history in Azure Databricks. The upper pane has no option for it. Could you please help me to get it back ? Or is there any new option for it ?

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot for reference?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that it was working before , you just need to zoom-in to 110% or less and you should have that appears on the browser , on higher zoom it disappears . See the the snapshot below .

[image]